# MySql normalization of string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using friendly_urls, and want to have an sqlfield 'friendly_url' which will depend on the field 'title'.  So, if my title field is "This is My Title", my friendly_url field will be "this_is_my_title".

The problem is, while being a Portuguese website, the title field will often have characters like 'ç', 'ã', 'é', etc...

What is the best way (in mySql, if possible, in PHP if necessary), to turn "António Girão" to  "antonio_girao"?

Thank you very much

Comment: You probably want to search for "slug", which is the usual name for the "this_is_my_title" URL segment based on a string. Doing this is sometimes called "slugifying" :)

Comment: [MySQL supports setting the collation on a specific column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html), so you could set it to be a collation that doesn't include the accents you list.  In theory it should store the character without the accent, but test first.  BTW: Spaces in URLS get converted to "%20" per space -- underscores aren't necessary.

Comment: OMG Ponies, if you put this as an answer and give me the correct collation, i will accept it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force method would be to use [strtr](http://php.net/strtr) to do in-place replacements:

```
strtr($string, "ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåā ", "aaaaaaaaaaaaa_")
```

Comment: i would really love to do it as a Default Value in MySql

Comment: You can probably force some of this with character set translations in MySQL - but the `<space>` to `_` wouldn't work, since they're fundamentally different characters. That you'd have to use a string search/replace for.

Answer (score 2):

You could be done in MySQL [using triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) however I suppose it would be easier for you to do this using PHP. Here's [`Doctrine_Inflector::urlize()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Inflector.php) method that removes/replaces unwanted characters from string. You can use it.